# How can I change Qml TextField echoMode Password displayed asterisks?

Tags: qt, qml, textfield

How can I change Qml TextField echoMode Password displayed asterisks with another char?

```
TextField {
    id: textId
    anchors.fill: parent
    font {
        pixelSize: 20
    }
    echoMode: TextInput.PasswordEchoOnEdit
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`passwordCharacter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#passwordCharacter-prop) property. It is a property of `TextInput`, but inherited by `TextField`.